# How to scroll an array every 10 ms and verify if an element correspond to the current time value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, real-time

I have a audio file and an array that has in its elements a float value (rounded to 10ms) corresponding to the moment in which a note is played. While the audio file is playing, i want to write in the console, when the audio's current time value corresponds to one of the elements in the array, that exact element.
I did this by using setInterval (setting 10ms for the interval), but my problem is that sometimes my function writes the same element zero, two or three times. I want the function to write every element exactly 1 time.

I already tried changing the interval, but i always have the same problem.

...

```
//events_num is my array
//audio.currentTime is the time of the audio file while playing

function write() {
  for(var i=0; i<events_num.length; i++) {
    if(events_num[i] >= (audio.currentTime-0.005) && events_num[i] < (audio.currentTime+0.005)) {
      console.log(events_num[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

setInterval(write, 10);
```

...

if events_num = [3.42, 3.98, 3.99, 4.60, 5, 5.57] and i start my audio from 00:00, i want the output in the console to be:
3.42, 3.98, 3.99, 4.60, 5, 5.57
and not (for example)
3.42(2), 3.98, 3.99(3), 4.60, 5.57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there I would just use a "lazy" approach and save the timestamps as a simple struct like

```
{
  timestamp: number,
  used: boolean
}
```

so as soon as the time has been published/used the system can mark it to not use it again.
Because the problem lies in the time and the if you are using.

Comment: That worked, but i have another problem now. If i restart my audio file without refreshing the page, the booleans result to be true (meaning that every event has been already played). I tried to call a function that brings back the booleans to false and it works, but the previous problem returns. Any ideas? My function is:                  
 function reset() {
  var curTime = audio.currentTime;
  for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    if(events[i].time > curTime)
      events[i].played = false;
  }
} setInterval(reset, 100);

Comment: What does restart in this case mean? You start completely from the beginning or can you jump from timestamp to timestamp as well?

Comment: I mean i can jump to a different timestamp (I use a HTML audio controls tag to do that).